# Correct usage of numpy.savetxt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

### TL;DR

This **question** is equivalent to asking: how can I save this array:

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.array([np.array([np.array([1,1,1]),np.array([1,1,1])]),np.array([np.array([1,1,1,3]),np.array([1,1,1,3])])])
```

with output:

```
>>>> ar

array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 3],
        [1, 1, 1, 3]]])
```

using `np.savetxt('test1.txt',ar)` ?

---

### Context

This question might be basic but it's still a little confusing. I'm trying to store parameters of a configuration `([[x0,x1,...,x8],[x01,x11,...,x81],...[x0n, x1n,...,x8n]])` + results from that configuration `([[y0,y1,...,y8,y9],[y01,y11,...,y81,y91],...[y0n, y1n,...,y8n,y9n]])` inside a "master" array. I'm trying this

```
import numpy as np
import random

def combine_shuffle_test(n): #generating data
    a, b = [], []
    for i in range(random.randint(0,5)):
        a.append(np.random.normal(0,1,8))
        b.append(np.random.normal(0,1,9))
    return a,b

master_configs =[] # start with an empty list
master_evols = []  # 

for i in range(2):
    try:
        master_configs, master_evols = np.array(np.loadtxt('master_results.txt',delimiter=', ')) #To load
    except:
        pass
    
    fil_cfgs, fil_res_evol = combine_shuffle_test(100) #data (np.arrays) are extracted from this combine_shuffle_test function
    master_configs.append(fil_cfgs)
    master_evols.append(fil_res_evol)
    np.savetxt('master_results.txt', np.array([master_configs,master_evols]), fmt='%1.6f', newline='\n', delimiter=', ') #To save
```

but I get the ValueError

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-a9d634ac3893> in <module>
     12     master_configs.append(fil_cfgs)
     13     master_evols.append(fil_res_evol)
---> 14     np.savetxt('master_results.txt', np.array([master_configs,master_evols]), fmt='%1.6f', newline='\n', delimiter=', ') #To save

<__array_function__ internals> in savetxt(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments, encoding)
   1369         # Handle 1-dimensional arrays
   1370         if X.ndim == 0 or X.ndim > 2:
-> 1371             raise ValueError(
   1372                 "Expected 1D or 2D array, got %dD array instead" % X.ndim)
   1373         elif X.ndim == 1:

ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 3D array instead
```

**Question**: what I'm I missing here? Are there more efficent ways to store `fil_cgs`, `fil_res_evol` in the same `.txt` file over and over inside the `for`-loop?

The **main idea** of this is to iterate a good amount of times to extract "interesting" data coming from `combine_shuffle_test` which is really solving differential equations and comparing analytical and numerical results.

Comment: `np.array([master_configs, master_evols])` will take the two 2D arrays and make it a 3D array with the total number of slices in the first dimension to be 2.  This is why `np.savetxt` is reporting an error because it is designed to only write 1D or 2D arrays.  If it is your intent to put the `master_evols` as additional rows on top of `master_configs`, you should be doing `np.hstack([master_configs, master_evols])`.  I suspect this is only a small part of your problem.  As for what is "more efficient", I wouldn't know how to answer this without knowing more of what your problem is.

Comment: @rayryeng very useful comment, thanks! what should I do if `master_configs` and `master_evols` have different sizes? (e.g., 5 and 10). I'm getting `ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 2, the array at index 0 has size 10 and the array at index 1 has size 5`

Comment: `savetxt` creates a `csv` style text - that is a simple table with consistent rows and columns.  The result should be readable by `loadtxt`.Thus the array should be 2d. Use `np.save` for more general array saves.

Comment: If the total number of columns is the same, there shouldn't be a problem.  If the number of columns differs, you wouldn't be able to use `np.savetxt`.  I also misread the code.  I would recommend concatenating all of your results, then writing to file when you're done.  Right now it's appending 2D arrays to a list that will inevitably be 3D arrays.  If it's your intent to save this in a readable form, you wouldn't be able to place them both in the same file unless you put some hacks in (like placing `NaN` for those positions that don't line up).  I'd recommend hpaulj's way of generic saves.

Comment: By giving `savetxt` an open file rather than filename, it is possible to do multiple writes to the the same file.  But reading such a file will be awkward, though not impossible, especially if the number of columns differs between sections.  Basically it requires multiple loads.  `savetxt` isn't fancy.  It just iterates on rows of the array, and does a simple file write of a `fmt%tuple(row)` string.